# Centering string on greeting

Tags: python, string, center

I'm trying to center this greeting in between the hashtags.

```
def setup():
    print("#" * 100)
    welcome = "Welcome to my adventure game!"
    welcome.center(25)
    print(welcome)
    print("#" * 100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all due respect, I don't understand how you didn't realize this.

```
    welcome = welcome.center(100)
```

Comment: Well, I'm just a kid trying to learn python. Now I feel bad.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do it mathematically:

```
def setup():
    print("#" * 100)
    welcome = "Welcome to my adventure game!"
    spacer = ' ' * (50 - len(welcome) // 2)
    print(spacer + welcome)
    print("#" * 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to surround he welcome message with something other than space use the second argument of center.

```
print(welcome.center(100, "#"))
```